# Using Custom assets for transaction fees

Tags: pallet, transactions

I am trying to create some custom assets using pallet_assets and I want to pay the transaction fees for some extrinsics using the created custom asset. How can I achieve so ?

Comment: already answered here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-to-pay-transaction-fees-using-the-custom-token-created-by-using-pallet-asset

Comment: @EricSegall did you solved this??

Comment: @AmitKumarYadav No :(