# How to pay transaction fees using the custom token created by using pallet_assets?

Tags: pallet, balances, assets, sufficient

At the moment the transaction fee is payed as the native token in the substrate node template. When I create a new asset_id(say BAT) a fungible asset using pallet_assets, How can I now pay the transaction fees using this BAT token?

Comment: This is the base currency if you have not otherwise added other assets. Have you added a pallet? Or created another instance of one outside balances?

Comment: so say i've created a new fungible asset(BAT token) using pallet_assets, i want to be able to pay the transactions fees for this node using the created BAT token if user has the balance

Comment: also there is pallet_asset_tx_payment (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.19/frame/transaction-payment/asset-tx-payment). Should i be using this to solve this? ... If so, is there any examples that we can look at?

Comment: @rustyloaki are you able to change your tx_fee from native to asset(BAT token)?

Answer (score 8):

1. In order to do this you will need in your runtime the `pallet_asset_tx_payment` pallet. Here's an example of the [configuration](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/030db02f876461c19fc617dd7899536881b4ca26/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L561-L573).
   (the pallet would need to be added into the `construct_runtime!` etc. See statemint as an example).
2. Now that that type is available it needs to be added into the tuple that is the SignedExtra type like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/030db02f876461c19fc617dd7899536881b4ca26/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L669). As you can see that then becomes part of the `UncheckedExtrinsic` type.
3. Then on the client side when you construct the signed transaction the SignedExtra needs to be encoded too (eg. [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/6012d2a75e3ea50209f9f5ab9638e6ee9e91a900/subxt/src/client.rs#L283)).

Comment: On the polkadot-js front there's an issue raised to allow this to be specified on the front end: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7812

Comment: Have you ever done this ??
It also requires to edit ```UncheckedExtrinsic``` type inside the ```command_helper.rs``` file under node. There we have to call the ```from``` function with two arguments, balance and ```Option<AssetId>``` which you have skipped. Please provide some examples of the ```command_helper.rs``` file as well.
Also can you tell how to encode ```SignedExtra``` on client side?

Comment: @Squirrel is it possible to contruct the `SignedExtra` which is needed by pallet_asset_tx_payment ?

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8063/where-do-i-add-a-signedextension-in-a-subxt-call

Comment: `error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>: hidden_include::traits::fungible::Unbalanced<AccountId32>` is not satisfied`. Getting this error, can someone face this error while configuring `pallet_asset_tx_payment`

Answer (score 2):

We do this at Encointer, the full code including a client that can pay in the custom asset can be found at https://github.com/encointer/encointer-node. I highlight the most important things here:

#### Runtime

You need to include the pallet-asset-tx-payment: https://github.com/encointer/encointer-node/blob/6b5f32350874a099178115de09b163e2b2237e61/runtime/src/lib.rs#L467. We have defined our own `OnChargeTransaction` because we don't use the pallet-assets. You can just use the one that pallet-assets exposes.

You need to add it to the signed extension: https://github.com/encointer/encointer-node/blob/6b5f32350874a099178115de09b163e2b2237e61/runtime/src/lib.rs#L523.

This will add an `Option<AssetId>` to the signed extension. If it is `Some` in the extrinsic, it will use the defined asset as fee-payment token; otherwise it falls back to the native token.

#### Client

In our encointer-client cli we use the substrate-api-client (subxt-alternative) library to connect to it: https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client.

Here, we define the signed extension type in extrinsic format: https://github.com/encointer/encointer-node/blob/6b5f32350874a099178115de09b163e2b2237e61/client/encointer-api-client-extension/src/extrinsic_params.rs#L17. It says `CommunityIdentifier` here because we don't use the pallet-assets. You will put `AssetId` there.

At this point we define that we want to pay with the custom asset: https://github.com/encointer/encointer-node/blob/6b5f32350874a099178115de09b163e2b2237e61/client/src/main.rs#L331.

##### Polkadot-js/apps sidenote

The `SignedExtension` is not exposed in the metadata, hence you need to hardcode it. You need to manually add it to the polkadot-js/api type registry, see https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/c484456c12dbeeaccc701ec89d891e5e3f53a4cc/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec/encointer-para.ts#L247.

This polkadot-js/apps fix is needed because otherwise polkadot-js/apps is not able to correctly interpret blocks that contain an extrinsic paid in the non-native asset, i.e., where the asset-tx-payment signed extension was `Some<AssetId>`.

Comment: how can i add to substrate client in which file should i make changes?

Comment: You can use subxt as documented [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8063/where-do-i-add-a-signedextension-in-a-subxt-call).