# Subxt call to custom pallet method returning `wasm 'unreachable'` - (`TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction`)

Tags: parachain, pallet, extrinsic, substrate-parachain-template, subxt

So I am trying to submit `extrinsics` to a running parachain node using subxt, but encounter a Codec error.

The parachain is based on the [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template), the relay chain is compiled directly from the [Polkadot repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot), and I am using the latest subxt version (v0.28.0). Both the relay chain and the parachain are using the crates from the `polkadot-v0.9.37` branch of Substrate.

The para- and relay chains are able to connect and finalize authored blocks, and subxt is able to subscribe to this finalization.

However, trying to submit custom extrinsics results in the following errors:

Error printed by the parachain node:

```
[Parachain] panicked at 'Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Codec error', <PARACHAIN_PATH>/runtime/src/lib.rs:516:1
```

Error printed by the subxt application (I tried to format it with newlines for better readability):

```
Rpc error: RPC error: RPC call failed: ErrorObject {
    code: ServerError(1002), message: "Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: 
    Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
    0: 0x1d6993 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x3a74 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h0c053f1c32a1ef70\
    2: 0x15d8cc - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\
\", 
data: Some(RawValue("RuntimeApi(\"Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap:
wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\
WASM backtrace:
    0: 0x1d6993 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\
    1: 0x3a74 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h0c053f1c32a1ef70\
    2: 0x15d8cc - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\
\")")) }
```

I have not been able to find any documentation or posts by anyone else encountering this issue. I am trying to submit an extrinsic using subxt as seen here:

```rust
let pair = subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair::from_string_with_seed(<SEED_HEX>, None).unwrap();
    let signer: PairSigner<SubstrateConfig, subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair> = PairSigner::<SubstrateConfig, subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair>::new(pair.0);

    let payload = chain_apis::energychain_api::api::tx().energychain().create_energy_offer(500, 4);

    match connection.get_api().tx().validate(&payload) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Call okay!"),
        Err(e) => println!("Error from call: {:?}", e),
    }

    let tx_in_block = connection.get_api().tx()
        .sign_and_submit_then_watch_default(&payload, &signer)
        .await?;
```

Before the error is printed, the `validate` match prints out `Call okay!`.

The parachain I am trying to submit the extrinsic to has the following call defined:

```rust
#[pallet::weight(1000)]
#[pallet::call_index(1)]
pub fn create_energy_offer(origin: OriginFor<T>, amount: u16, price: u8) -> DispatchResult {
    let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

    ensure!(amount > T::EnergyOfferMinW::get(), Error::<T>::EnergyOfferNotEnoughWatts);

    let energy_offer = EnergyOffer { seller: who.clone(), amount: amount.clone(), price: price.clone() };

    let energy_offer_id = T::Hashing::hash_of(&energy_offer);
    EnergyOffers::<T>::insert(energy_offer_id, energy_offer.clone());

    Self::deposit_event(Event::EnergyOfferCreated(energy_offer.amount.clone(), energy_offer.price.clone(), who, energy_offer_id));

    Ok(())
}
```

Any insights into the possible origin of this issue and, ideally, how it could be resolved is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess offhand is that the parachain has slightly different "extra" properties that it expects to see in a transaction from those that the default `SubstrateConfig::ExtraParams` is adding (this would lead to the node being unable to validate the TX and I wouldn't be surprised if it would spit out a codec error because the bytes it's trying to decode aren't what it expects). For the default substrate node, what it expects is defined here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/890451221db37176e13cb1a306246f02de80590a/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1847. Is that the same for the parachain?

Comment: This is the current `SignedExtra` of my parachain:

```/// The SignedExtension to the basic transaction logic.
pub type SignedExtra = (
 frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
 frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
 frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
 frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
 frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
 frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
 frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
 pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
);```

Should I add something to it, in order to submit transactions defined in my own pallet?

Comment: Adding my custom structs to the type gives `the trait 'SignedExtension' is not implemented for ...`, I assume that I should implement this trade for all the structs? Any good documentation/examples I can follow on that?

Comment: In Subxt, extrinsic params are configured by setting this type in the Config that you use: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/81494027c8f5ae62d44883167585d5e557f0fcba/subxt/src/config/mod.rs#L60. I'd have a look at the trait that you need to impl (https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/81494027c8f5ae62d44883167585d5e557f0fcba/subxt/src/config/extrinsic_params.rs#L16) and at how SubstrateConfig impls this (https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/81494027c8f5ae62d44883167585d5e557f0fcba/subxt/src/config/substrate.rs#L30)

Comment: I wonder whether you've resolved this issue? If not, I'd suggest opening an issue in the Subxt repository and if you're able to give some steps to reproduce your issue, we'd be able to dig more into it :)

Comment: (also perhaps https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8063/where-do-i-add-a-signedextension-in-a-subxt-call/8067#8067 would help)