# how i can pay transaction fees through custom token

Tags: assets, blockchain, transaction-fees

i am currently using substrate full node . and i have created non native  custom  tokens through assets like of name KAR . when i transfer these custom tokens i.e KAR from one account to another the transaction fees is deducting through native tokens . can anyone please tell me how we can use these non native (custom) tokens i.e KAR for transaction fees  and where i have to  make  changes to do this .

i have followed [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-to-pay-transaction-fees-using-the-custom-token-created-by-using-pallet-asset) and made an Api for `SignedExtension` but still the fees is getting deducted from the native token the link for my api is [api](https://github.com/karanvir12/Asset_Api.git)

Comment: if your Substrate chain implements the assets pallet, this post should answer your question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-to-pay-transaction-fees-using-the-custom-token-created-by-using-pallet-asset?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pay transaction fees using the custom token created by using pallet\_assets?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-to-pay-transaction-fees-using-the-custom-token-created-by-using-pallet-asset)

Comment: i have followed [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-to-pay-transaction-fees-using-the-custom-token-created-by-using-pallet-asset) and made an Api for `SignedExtension` but still the fees is getting deducted from the native token the link for my api is [api](https://github.com/karanvir12/Asset_Api.git)